# Validating fields with dynamic table names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have N amounts of tables like this:

```
foo_1_data
(
    id int,
    some_foo_data_1 varchar(100),
    some_foo_data_2 char(5)
)

foo_2_data
(
    id  int,
    some_foo_data_1 varchar(100),
    some_foo_data_2 char(5)
)

bar_1_data
(
    id int,
    some_bar_data_1 decimal(10,2),
    some_bar_data_2 datetime
)

bar_2_data
(
    id int,
    some_bar_data_1 decimal(10,2),
    some_bar_data_2 datetime
)
```

The tables are based on different data - `foo_data` and `bar_data` - and are user generated and there is an ID - `foo_N_data` and `bar_N_data` - set.

Now I want to implement validation on records on these tables through a Stored Procedure to follow certain business rules on the receiving end, which we don't have control over.

Example:

1. `some_foo_data_1` is a varchar(100) is a name and in our system it can be
   between 0 and 100 characters but on the receiving end it needs to be
   between 2 and 70 characters.
2. `some_bar_data_1` is a decimal(10.2) and it needs to be between 0 and
   100 (let's say it's a percentage)

We tried and implement Stored Procedures called, for example, `sp_rule_name`, that takes the original table and column and validated it through `Dynamic SQL` like this:

```
EXEC('SELECT ' + @column_to_validate + ' FROM ' + @table_to_validate + ' WHERE ...')
```

This creates re-usable code between the different validation procedures (one for each different data set - one for `foo_data` and one for `bar_data`) but the code is hard to understand and maintain because of the mixture of `T-SQL` and `Dynamic SQL`. We also tried using `functions` on the fields but dropped it because of slow performance.

**Is there an efficient and re-usable way to validate data from dynamic tablas?**

Note: We know how the table structure will look like of both `foo` and `bar` but we don't know the N value so we can't call it directly.

Comment: Having your users run DDL statements in your database is bad practice in most cases, not to mention a security hazard. If possible, I would recommend re-think this entire approach.

Comment: Also, are you really working with 2005 version? If possible, you should upgrade it at least to 2012 version ([since even 2008 is now on extended support ending next year](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I had faced a similar situation and I had to rely on dynamic SQL to get the job done. But troubleshooting it and even reading it was a pain.
I did a small change and that helped in solving the troubleshooting/reading problem especially if it's only SELECT on the underlying table

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/MUBB10917)**</kbd>

```
create proc sp_rule_name  @tblName varchar(100)
as 
begin
    declare @sql varchar(max);
    set @sql =' CREATE VIEW tempView  AS  SELECT * FROM '+ @tblName+ ' ;'
    exec (@sql)
    -- after this normal SQL syntax using tempView object for all sort of validations. No need for dynamic SQL
    select * from tempView;
end
go

create table foo_1_data (
    id int,
    some_foo_data_1 varchar(100),
    some_foo_data_2 char(5)
);
insert into foo_1_data values
(1,'345453','56666');



execute sp_rule_name N'foo_1_data';
```